# CSS - Is it possible to select multiple different child elements within a parent without repeating the parent?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've been pawing over CSS selectors all afternoon in an attempt to find an answer to this because it seems so simple but I cannot for the life of me find any solution.

Given a structure similar to:

```
<div id="about>
    <h1></h1>
    <h2></h2>
    <h3></h3>
</div>
```

I want to make all of the headers a different typeface specific to this division using one selector.

My selectors would normally have been:

```
#about h1,
#about h2,
#about h3 {
}
```

Which now really appears to be inefficient. Is there a way to collate the ID?

```
#about h1 + h2 + h3 (incorrect)
```

Is there something akin to:

```
#about (h1,h2,h3)
```

I feel as if this should be obvious but I have never seen such a selection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To complete Guffa answer, if you cannot use server side preprocessing and you have to target only Firefox and Chrome you can also use

```
:-moz-any( selector[, selector]* )
:-webkit-any( selector[, selector]* )
```

in your case you will use this pseudoclass in this way

```
#about :-moz-any(h1, h2, h3) { ... }
```

otherwise the only crossbrowser method without using less or sass that reduce the amount of rules is the universal selector

```
#about > *
```

but this will target every immediate child of `#about` and it is intrinsically inefficient.

---

### Update 2023

Now browsers support `:is` and `:where` pseudoclasses, so you may use them, e.g.:

```
#about :is(h1, h2, h3) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Small note, using * as a selector is extremely slow, and should be avoided when possible.
CSS engines are working right to left, meaning that the engine will first match any * matching elements, which are all elements, and then check each one of them for #about parent.

Comment: @PeledRoy as I mentioned on my last statement :)

Comment: Correct, just wanted to expand further on the subject.

Comment: Maybe in the near future (2013?) when vendors start adopting level 4 selectors, we can start answering with `#about > :matches(h1, h2, h3)`.

Answer (score 8):

In plain CSS it's not possible. If you set a class on the header tags you can target them with a single selector.

Using something like [less](http://lesscss.org/), you can do:

```
#about {
  h1, h2, h3 { ... }
}
```

Comment: Someone just suggested SASS as well which I believe is of similar concept.

Answer (score 5):

The `:is()` selector should do what you mention.
For your specific example

```
<div id="about">
    <h1>My</h1>
    <h2>Name</h2>
    <h3>Is</h3>
```

, you could use the is() selector as

```
#about :is(h1,h2,h3) {
  color:red;  //or whatever property you want to add
}
```

Check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McC4QkCvbaY) for more info.