# CSS selector for some childs with same parent

Tags: css

I am writing some rules in CSS for some elements that shares the same parent.

```
#parent_id li
#parent_id label, 
#parent_id input, 
#parent_id select { ... }
```

Is there an alternative syntax to avoid to repeat the parent id?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999568/css-is-it-possible-to-select-multiple-different-child-elements-within-a-parent][1]




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999568/css-is-it-possible-to-select-multiple-different-child-elements-within-a-parent

possible duplicate of this question

Comment: Does `parent_id` contain anything else other than `li`, `label`, `input` and `select` elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not in pure CSS, but you can use some CSS preprocessor like:

- LESS CSS http://lesscss.org/
- Sass http://sass-lang.com/
- Switch CSS http://sourceforge.net/projects/switchcss/
- ...or other

Answer (score 2):

If those elements you're selecting are all the elements within the parent element, you could just apply the style to the parent element:

```
#parent_id {
     ....
}
```

Styles in there should be inherited down so that the elements inside it are get those styles as well.

Another option might be to use the universal `*` selector:

```
#parent_id * {
    ....
}
```

This will affect all elements at least one level below the `parent_id` element, but not `parent_id` itself. If you've got plain text in `parent_id` that you want to leave unaffected, this might be the one to use.

A third option would be to change your HTML markup so that the elements you want to affect have a class. Then your CSS could simply reference that class instead.

(btw - yes, I'm aware of LESS/SASS/etc, but I didn't think there was much value in posting the same answer as everone else)

Comment: That's not cascading. That's inheritance. Not all styles are inherited so simply specifying them on the parent element is almost always not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @BoltClock - you caught me; corrected the terminology. You're right, not all styles would be inherited, but for those that aren't that's why I also gave the second option. (he didn't specify what styles he's using, so I thought it best to offer both)

Comment: `#parent_id *` would not target all elements one level below the parent, it would target *all* elements on *any* level below the parent. If targeting only direct children of an element is the goal, `#parent_id > *` should be used.

Comment: @Elise - sure. I was trying to match the semantics of the original selector from the question; he used a space; so that's what I used. The main point being that `#parent_id` itself doesn't get the styles. A `>` selector might be more appropriate, but without knowing more about the markup and the styles he's using, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: @Spudley This is true, I was merely nitpicking on your original wording :)

Comment: Thanks @Spudley. On this case it was only applied to those elements so I can't use the universal selector.

Answer (score 1):

CSS native dont support this. But you can use SASS/LESS:

```
#parent_id {
  label, input, select { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple css it is not possible. Try [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) to achieve this.